# How to interface start function, stop function to start a indefinite while loop and stop it using flask?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

Heres my question- I am using flask with python and html to create a web app. All i want to do is create 2 buttons in which one button in my html which inturn starts a while loop in my flask.py (server side) ie it calls a counter function and runs continously and when another button is pressed the loop should stop. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Minimal viable example of the python side below.  On the html side have your buttons call the `/start` and `/stop` endpoints.
If this is anything more than just proof of concept or single user application, Threading and global variables shouldn't be used like this.  Look into Celery/RQ to replace the tasks and Redis/a database for storing "global" variables.

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)
go = True
count = 0

def counter():
    global go
    while go:
        sleep(1)
        global count
        count += 1
        print(count)

@app.route('/start', methods=('GET','POST'))
def start():
    thread = Thread(target=counter)
    thread.start()
    return 'Started'

@app.route('/stop', methods=('GET','POST'))
def check():
    global go
    go = False
    return 'Stopped at: ' + str(count)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! But on new /start fails, after def start(): add a go = True and it work's great!